# Google Sheets using JavaScript functions and check box

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to use the "check box" operation of google sheets, and when the check box is true, then call to a function.
Someone can help me with that ?

Comment: What do you mean by Check Box? As in an input field checkbox?

Comment: A new feature that enable to create a clickable check box that return true or false on a click. I want to associate the check box to a function.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with HTML and Javascript? The google-sheets part is confusing me, does it need to relate to google-sheets or do you want an example of check boxes?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your checkbox is at `A1`, you could use this script to test when it's checked or unchecked (modified):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getA1Notation() == 'A1') {
    var value = range.getValue();
    range.setNote('Changed on ' + new Date() + ' to ' + range.getValue());
    if (typeof value === 'boolean' && value == true) {
      // Do something or call a function when the tick box is checked
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm unsure of exactly what you want to do in javascript, the Google Script editor may be useful for you.

In a Google Sheet, go to Tools > Script Editor. It should open a new page and create a new project with a blank function. This is where you can make new functions to be run within Google Sheets.

As an example I made a function called getSum:

```
function getSum(a,b) {
return a+b;
}
```

If you save this script and go back to Sheets, you can do `=getSum(1,2)` and it will return `3`

If you wanted to integrate this with a Tick Box, you could do `=IF(A1,getSum(1,2),getSum(2,2))`

In this case, when the tick box is checked, it will run the first statement, and return `3` , when the box is unchecked, it will return `4`

I'm not entirely sure on what you are trying to achieve with JavaScript, but this is one way to introduce custom functions (using Google Script).

Comment: Thank you for the details, appreciate it!